# How to speed up window slicing time series sequence code?

Tags: python, time-series, sequence, rolling-computation, sequential

I have the following code that helps me generate sequence of array for each ID for 30 Days slicing data for Machine learning.

My problem is that it took a very long time to run for very large dataframe with many ID(100000+) Time(1000 + period), and variables (100+)

Is that anyway to speed up the performance of this piece of code?

**The code i'm trying to speed up:**

```
sequence_length = 30 ＃window size
sequence_cols = df.iloc[:,2:].columns # features columns that going to pass as array

df= df.drop(columns='T')  #Dropped the time            
    
def gen_sequence(id_df, seq_length, seq_cols):
   data_array = id_df[seq_cols].values
   num_elements = data_array.shape[0]
   for start, stop in zip(range(0, num_elements-seq_length), range(seq_length, num_elements)):
        yield data_array[start:stop, :]
                
    
train_seq_gen = (list(gen_sequence(df[df['id']== id], sequence_length, 
                 sequence_cols)) for id in df['id'].unique())
        
train_seq_array = np.concatenate(list(train_seq_gen)).astype('float32')
train_seq_array.shape

My Dataframe looks something like this:

    id      T   V1 V2
    ID_1    1   0  3
    ID_1    2   5  4
    ID_1    3   8  1
    ID_2    1   7  1
    ID_2    2   3  3
    ID_2    3   5  4
    ID_2    4   2  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what kind of ML algorithm do you use? Most of the ML frameworks define data pipelines (e.g. [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)) which should be preferred both for code-readability and performance reasons.

That said there are a few no brainers I'd try.

- use pandas' [groupby](https://www.statology.org/pandas-groupby-index/) instead of df[df['id']== id] (note: using variable names such as "id" shadowing builtins is not cool)
- use numpy's [array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) instead of a custom slicing logic which does the same thing (but in an obscure way)
- preallocate a result variable using `X = np.zeros(<desired-shape>, dtype=np.float32)` and assign values to it `X[window_i] = <window_data>` instead of the creation of a list of numpy arrays and the use of `np.concatenate`

Comment: i'm trying to feed it to LSTM model using past 30 days to predict next 1 day label, so that i have to transform my dataframe for each ID into sequence of array, but it took too long to generate the sequence